# Unit testing a Get request in a spring project

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I developed an application which gets the details from the user via console and the data is stored in a Mongo database. After saving data is passed to angular frontend using spring api. The data is passed to the frontend without any error. Now I need to unit test the method which returns the list of books.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {

@Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepo;

@GetMapping("/books")
    public List<Book> getBooks(){
        return bookRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

BookRepository class extends with MongoRepository.

The unit test I've written so far.

```
    class BookControllerTest {

    private Controller controller;

    private BookRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void getBooksTest(){

        Book b1 = new Book("12345","James","male");
        Book b2 = new Book("67890","Vicky","Female");

        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        bookList.add(b1);
        bookList.add(b2);
        System.out.println(bookList);

        repository.save(b1);
        repository.save(b2);
        List<Book> newList = controller.getBooks();
        System.out.println(newList);

        assertEquals(bookList,newList);
    }

}
```

A java.lang.NullPointerException is obtained when trying to save the data to the repository and I think the array list 'newList' also null.

Please help me to solve this problem on how to test this method.

Comment: this should help. https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: I think you forgot to autowire "BookRepository repository" in BookControllerTest

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making a call to getAll the books, you need not any books to the repository first, instead you can use Mocking to mock the call to the repository.

```
@Mock
private BookRepository repository;

@Test
public void getBooksTest(){

    Book b1 = new Book("12345","James","male");
    Book b2 = new Book("67890","Vicky","Female");

    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    bookList.add(b1);
    bookList.add(b2);
    System.out.println(bookList);

    when(repository.findAll()).thenReturn(bookList);
    List<Book> newList = controller.getBooks();
    System.out.println(newList);

    assertEquals(2,newList.size());
}
```

Comment: It still makes a NullPointerException from the line '  when(repository.findAll()).thenReturn(bookList); '

Comment: @ArchieVon That indicates the Mock-annotation is not processed. Make sure to annotate your test class with @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) for junit5 or a similar annotation for junit4

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)` for this. This annotation will ensure you get a Spring Context including all beans you need to test your web layer. In addition, it will autoconfigure a `MockMvc` instance that you can use to access the endpoint.

Any other dependency of your `Controller` class should be mocked.

```
@WebMvcTest
// @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) required if you are using JUnit 4
public class PublicControllerJUnit4Test {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
   
  @MockBean
  private BookRepository bookRepository;

  @Test
  public void testMe() throws Exception {

    Book b1 = new Book("12345","James","male");
    Book b2 = new Book("67890","Vicky","Female");

    when(bookRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(List.of(b1, b2));

    this.mockMvc
      .perform(get("/api/books"))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].isbn", is("12345")));
  }

}
```

With [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) you can then verify the body of the HTTP response.

You can follow the [Testing Guide from Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) for more information on this.